# JSON Enconding Issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, cordova

Hi I am developing a mobile app using phonegap and I am querying the MySQL database through ajax (jsonp).  However I have an issue when special characters are returned as they are displayed as "?" instead for example Ż.

At the moment in my PHP I have added this, however it did not do the trick:
`header('content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');`

Is anyone aware of any other charset that can be used which includes special characters like the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is first

a) Fix the db tables 
   Make sure that tables defined with proper character set 
  e.g

```
CREATE TABLE `types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

b) After connection to db  ensure following things

[SET NAMES 'utf8';](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql)

[I also run following ]

```
 SET  character_set_client  ='utf8',
 character_set_connection ='utf8',
 character_set_database  ='utf8',
 character_set_results   ='utf8',
 character_set_server    ='utf8',
 collation_connection    ='utf8_general_ci',
 collation_database      ='utf8_general_ci',
 collation_server        ='utf8_general_ci'
```

c) Finally set proper [content type for the html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460349/charset-utf8-not-working-in-my-php-page)

hope this will help you

Comment: since I have a PDO, for part (b) of your answer, would I set the characterset as follows?

$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET character_set_client    = utf8,
           character_set_connection  = utf8,
           character_set_database   = utf8,
           character_set_results    = utf8,
           character_set_server     = utf8,
           collation_connection     = utf8_general_ci,
           collation_database       = utf8_general_ci,
           collation_server         = utf8_general_ci',
); 


$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

Comment: I never used PDO ,and that init command seems to have bug with php 5.3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424343/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-with-pdo . Therefore, your best bet is to run : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978481/pdoexec-or-pdoquery

Answer (score 0):

You're working with a MySQL database? So try to set a utf8 charset to the database connection like:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1',TRUE); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
```

Or try UTF-8 encoding

```
string utf8_encode ( string $data )
```

**Parameters:**

```
data
An ISO-8859-1 string.
```

**Return Values:**

```
Returns the UTF-8 translation of data.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSON implementation standards, all JSON data must be encoded in UTF format, the default format being UTF-8.
But you can always use other UTF formats, such as UTF-32BE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-16LE.

For detailed standards and information, visit [ietf standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).