# Cant get data from table using PHP/PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

im trying to retrieve data from my table only for some reason I receive a syntax error...

Can anybody see where i may be going wrong?

```
    $cid = $_GET['id']; 

    $username = 'liam';
    $password ='';  

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM directory WHERE ID = :cid');
$data->bindValue(":cid", $cid);

foreach($data as $row) {


    print_r($row). '<br />';
}
```

---

**Error**

```
 ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':cid' at line 1
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the exact error message you get.

Comment: Sorry, updated my question

Comment: I think you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978481/pdoexec-or-pdoquery

Comment: @Liam, like I said, make sure WHERE ID = :cid' is not suppose to be WHERE id = :cid'

Comment: You also do not seem to naming a database in your new PDO stmt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM directory WHERE ID = :cid');
$data->bindValue(":cid", $cid);
```

You have to bind variables before querying DB...

Take a look at the example on the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 1):

You are running the query instead of preparing it.

Change

```
$conn->query
```

to

```
$conn->prepare
```

`query()` simply runs a given query as is. `prepare()` sends the prepared statement to your database after which it can be run with bound parameters.

I also see you are using the MySQL driver with PDO. When working with MySQL you have to disable emulated prepared statements:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

For more information see: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
$data = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM directory WHERE ID = :cid');
$data->bindValue(":cid", $cid);
```

Note the use of `prepare()` rather than `query()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF-8');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
define('PDO_DSN', 'mysql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE . ';charset=' .
DB_CHARSET);

try {

$db = new PDO(PDO_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND 
=> "SET NAMES UTF8"));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Make sure ID is capital letter in your table!!

```
$data = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM directory WHERE ID = :cid');
```

Maybe here I would use bindParam instead of bindValue()

```
$data->bindValue(':cid', $cid);
$data->execute();
$result = $data->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row) {


print_r($row). '<br />';
}
```

Comment: And what if the field in his table is not capital ID? Just wondering why it had to be in capital ..

Comment: @dbf, there is a difference between WHERE ID = 1 and WHERE id = 1

Comment: Yeah the difference is one is capitalized and the other is not, my question was why does this matter ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a database name in your connect line, nor am I seeing a `use` clause in your script.