# PHP - Replace characters in a string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, str-replace

I have read a number of articles on `str_replace()` on here and other resources, and not found the answer to my problem.

Here’s the string I have a problem with which is stored in `$title` ...

```
Paul McCartney's Theme From The Film "The Honorary Consul”
```

Here’s the code I’m using ...

`str_replace(‘“‘,’ ‘,$title);`

For some reason, the code above is completely ignoring this string, and a number of others similar.

I think it may be because of the Apostrophe as the above code works fine for strings which don’t have apostrophe’s as part of the text.

I need to keep the apostrophe in the title, but I’m not so worried about the “

However, if someone can suggest a way to keep both, in the same string, and add the whole string in a `MySQL INSERT` command string, that would be the best result for me.

Comment: USE PREPARED PDO STATEMENTS!!!! You don't need to worry about this with prepared statements. If you are not using them - you should start immediately as you probably are open to SQL injection.

Comment: @tftd can you post an example?]

Comment: @RichStarkie http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: The guys above have already posted more than enough. And because you might get confused at some point should you pdo `exec` or `execute` - this is an extra bonus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849105/pdoexec-or-pdoexecute. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

On php.net are good examples, just look on manual.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
$title = 'Paul McCartney\'s Theme From The Film "The Honorary Consul”';
str_replace('”',' ', $title);
```

Anyway, I would recommend you to use Prepared Statements to insert your data.

Follow this example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: I would escape the `’` if i could, but the `$title` variable comes from an API (from a highly trusted and well respected source)

Comment: @RichStarkie what does var_dump($title) return? Probably it is already escaped.

Comment: @RichStarkie ok, you don't need to escape it. Just use the second line of my code. You have been using the character `‘`, which is wrong. It should be `'`.

Comment: thats the command I'm already using, but its not working :( it appears the SO app doesn't translate `'` properly :(

Comment: @RichStarkie what does `var_dump(str_replace('”',' ', $title));` return?

Comment: will have to run the whole script, which will take an hour or so, (this record is about a quarter of the way though the data set) the MySQL statement though is `INSERT INTO tablename ( trackId, releaseID, trackTitle, artistId, trackPosition) VALUES ('3820941 - 0002', '3820941', 'Paul McCartney's Theme From The Film "The Honorary Consul"', '273394', 'A2' )`

Comment: `string(58) "Paul McCartney's Theme From The Film "The Honorary Consul"" ` is the response @reza

Comment: @RichStarkie So you don't have `”` you have a `"`. But anyways don't fix that, this isn't the answer. Do it the right way, parameterize your query.